# Object reference not set to an instance of an object On Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure-sql-database

I can't find "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in Azure Data Studio.I made a log analytic workspace and still happen this error.Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you uninstall Azure Data Studio, re-install and run it as an Administrator, I faced similar issue once but the above steps solved it. Also, it would be great if you can provide more details like Azure Data Studio version, steps you followed etc. to make it more easier

Comment: I am glad that the response helped, can you mark it as an answer below so others who face similar issue can get benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

Can you uninstall Azure Data Studio, re-install and run it as an Administrator, I faced similar issue once but the above steps solved it